# ESP32 Freertos: SPI task blocks other task (even on different core!!)

Tags: esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

[image: This is serial output. It did connected to Wifi, it just never ran task 2]I'm developing high frequency DAQ based on ESP32 and freeRTOS.There will be 2 task, first task will run on core 0, communicating with sensors to collect data at 4000SPS, using SPI bus. Task 2 will run on core 1, receiving data from first task and send it async over TCP. Ideally, task 2 should send data while task 1 collecting latest one, simultaneously (dual core, right?)
When I do a test run, I let SPI bus run as fast as possible, but it just keep blocking task 2 from ever running!! I don't want to use vTaskDelay(1), as it would affect rate of collecting data. What should I do now, to let both task run concurrently? Thanks!!

```
   void inFromSensor(void *parameter)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
      //  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
        SPI.write(0b000011100);
        SPI.write(0b000011100);
        SPI.write(0b000011100);
        SPI.endTransaction();
        // vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        // for (int i = 0; i < 88; i++)
        // {
        //     testBuffer1[i] = 8;
        //     itoa(testBuffer1[i], &buffer1[i], 10);
        // }
        // buffer1[0] = '1';
        // buffer1[87] = '\n';

        // UBaseType_t res = xRingbufferSend(buf_handle, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        // if (res != pdTRUE)
        // {
        //     printf("Failed to send item\n");
        // }
        
        TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect = TIMG_WDT_WKEY_VALUE;
        TIMERG0.wdt_feed = 1;
        TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect = 0;
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
void outToTCP(void *parameter)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Serial.println("a");
        WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();
        if (client)
        {
            Serial.println("client connected");
            while (client.connected())
            {
                unsigned long start = millis();
                while (millis() - start < 5000)
                {
                    size_t item_size;
                    char *item = (char *)xRingbufferReceive(buf_handle, &item_size, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
                    if (item != NULL)
                    {
                        client.write(item);
                        //Return Item
                        vRingbufferReturnItem(buf_handle, (void *)item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Failed to receive item
                        printf("Failed to receive item\n");
                    }
                }
                Serial.println("done");
                return;
            }

            client.stop();
            Serial.println("Client disconnected");
        }
        
        TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect = TIMG_WDT_WKEY_VALUE;
        TIMERG0.wdt_feed = 1;
        TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect = 0;
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(112500);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    SPI.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS);
    pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
    }
    wifiServer.begin();

    buf_handle = xRingbufferCreate(50280, RINGBUF_TYPE_NOSPLIT);
    if (buf_handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create ring buffer\n");
    }
    Serial.println("ready");
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        inFromSensor,      /* Task function. */
        "lowPriorityTask", /* name of task. */
        15000,             /* Stack size of task */
        NULL,              /* parameter of the task */
        4,                 /* priority of the task */
        NULL,              /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
        1);
    delay(500);



xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    outToTCP,           /* Task function. */
    "highPriorityTask", /* name of task. */
    15000,              /* Stack size of task */
    NULL,               /* parameter of the task */
    6,                  /* priority of the task */
    NULL,               /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
    0);
delay(500);

Serial.println("ready");}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please post the serial output.

Anyway, my guess is that Task 1 is hogging the core which runs the WiFi stack, so WiFi never gets a chance to connect. Yet Task 2 depends on WiFi to be connected. Additionally Task 2 is waiting for data to be available in the ring buffers, but your code doesn't post anything there.

Anyway, this is something that would benefit from a timer. If you need to run a sampling process at specific intervals, configure a timer with the interval, do the sampling in the interrupt and post this to your processing thread. This is much more deterministic than spinning in a loop, hogging an entire core. Plus it leaves the spare cycles to those tasks that need them (there are quite a few in addition to your code).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I have added screenshot of serial output, it did connect to Wifi though.

Comment: More info: even if I wrap everything in task 1 in non-blocking delay  if(millis()-start >=1000) {}, put taskYield() under, task 2 still never ran.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I just switched the order of creation of task ( xTaskCreatedPinnedToCore()), create task 2 first, then task 1. Looks like in the first situation, task 1, after being created, run continuously, thus task 2 never had a chance to be created!

Answer (score 0):

```
void inFromSensor(void *parameter)
{
     VTaskDelay(NULL) // this will prevent task from running right after it is initialised, NULL parameter known that it is asking itself to delay.
    for (;;)
    {
    }
}

void setup()
{
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(inFromSensor,"lowPriorityTask", 15000, NULL,4,Task1,1);// give task handle such as Task1 and you will have to declare this on top.

delay(500);
// You can then here control the order of resuming the task
vTaskResume(Task1);// this will start the task and you should do this ideally

}
```